# How can I find which host I'm on within my .bashrc?

Tags: bash

I've created a git repository for my .bashrc that I pull from in my local machine and a remote machine. I want to run some commands for my localhost and not for my remote host.

Comment: The `hostname` or `uname -n` commands are likely to work.  I use `uname -n` in my startup scripts (but not `.bashrc`; I think running commands in that is too heavy; those go in my profile).

Comment: How can I do a string comparison on my `hostname`?

Comment: `if [ $(hostname) = "host1" ]; then ...host1 stuff...; fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
if [ ${HOSTNAME} == "ros-mbp.local" ]; then
  echo "host is local"
elif [ ${HOSTNAME} == "dev843.prn1.facebook.com" ]; then
  echo "host is remote"
else
  echo "host doesn't match."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution, which:

- works in both bash and sh
- supports `file pattern matching` for the hostnames

you may use this idiom:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=`hostname`
case "$HOST" in
   # examples of prefix matches:
   host1*) echo this matches host1 ;;
   host2*) echo this matches host2 ;;
   # and so on...

   # if none matched you use the default '*' pattern
   # which matches everything else
   *)     echo none matched: hostname is $HOST ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about `.bashrc` in particular, may I assume you are using `bash`? `bash` already sets the parameter `HOSTNAME` automatically.